# Making SQL entries appear only after current date - for a 'local events' page

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, where-clause

I've been making an events page for a community website I'm creating. It allows them to create new SQL entries for new events.

What I want is to **only display dates ahead of the current date**

Currently I have:

```
SELECT * FROM eventsDB ORDER BY eventdate ASC LIMIT 30";
```

But I suppose I have to add something like:

```
WHERE eventdate > NOW()
```

For the record the above doesnt work ↑

note: ($eventdate = date of event)

CRONTAB:

```
    <?php
class simpleCMS {

  var $host;
  var $username;
  var $password;
  var $table;

  public function display_public() {
    $q = "SELECT * 
          FROM eventsDB
          WHERE eventdate > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
          ORDER BY eventdate ASC
          LIMIT 30";
    $r = mysql_query($q);

    if ( $r !== false && mysql_num_rows($r) > 0 ) {
      while ( $a = mysql_fetch_assoc($r) ) {
        $title = stripslashes($a['title']);
        $author = stripslashes($a['author']);
        $bodytext = stripslashes($a['bodytext']);
        $eventdate = stripslashes($a['eventdate']);
        $created = stripslashes($a['created']);


        $entry_display .= <<<ENTRY_DISPLAY

    <div class="post">
        <table class="eventstable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="media/icons/icon_calendar.gif"/>  <b>$title </b></td>
    <td class="right">$eventdate </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="small">$bodytext <i>by $author</i></td>
  </tr>
</table>
    </div>

ENTRY_DISPLAY;
      }
    } else {
      $entry_display = <<<ENTRY_DISPLAY

    <h2> Your brand new Events Page! </h2>
    <p>
      No entries have been made yet.
      Follow my instructions to make a new event!
    </p>

ENTRY_DISPLAY;
    }
    $entry_display .= <<<ADMIN_OPTION

    <p class="admin_link">
      <a href="{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?admin=97538642"></a>
    </p>

ADMIN_OPTION;

    return $entry_display;
  }

  public function display_admin() {
    return <<<ADMIN_FORM

    <form action="{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}" method="post">

      <label for="title">Title:</label><br />
      <input name="title" id="title" type="text" maxlength="150" />
      <div class="clear"></div>

      <label for="bodytext">Body Text:</label><br />
      <textarea name="bodytext" id="bodytext"></textarea>
      <div class="clear"></div>

      <label for="author">Author:</label><br />
      <input name="author" id="author" type="text" maxlength="100" />
      <div class="clear"></div>

      <label for="eventdate">Date (DD/MM/YY):</label><br />
      <input name="eventdate" id="eventdate" type="text" maxlength="100" />
      <div class="clear"></div>

      <input type="submit" value="Create This Event!" />
    </form>

    <br />

    <a href="../events.php">Back to Events</a>

ADMIN_FORM;
  }

  public function write($p) {
    if ( $_POST['title'] )
      $title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
    if ( $_POST['bodytext'])
      $bodytext = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bodytext']);
    if ( $_POST['author'])
      $author = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['author']);
    if ( $_POST['eventdate'])
      $eventdate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['eventdate']);
    if ( $title && $bodytext && $author ) {
      $created = time();
      $sql = "INSERT INTO eventsDB VALUES('$title','$bodytext','$created','$author','$eventdate')";
      return mysql_query($sql);
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  public function connect() {
    mysql_connect($this->host,$this->username,$this->password) or die("Could not connect. " . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($this->table) or die("Could not select database. " . mysql_error());

    return $this->buildDB();
  }

  private function buildDB() {
    $sql = <<<MySQL_QUERY
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS eventsDB (
title       VARCHAR(150),
bodytext    TEXT,
created     VARCHAR(100),
author      VARCHAR(100),  
eventdate   VARCHAR(100),
)
MySQL_QUERY;

    return mysql_query($sql);
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: How are you storing eventdate?  Is it a UNIX timestamp?  A date string?

Comment: it is currently just VARCHAR 'DD/MM/YY' which is probably where im going wrong! I'm pretty new to SQL and PHP

Comment: If you want to store the date as a string and not a number, consider storing it YYYYMMDD.  That way, you can still make simple date comparisons and sorts.  If there's time information involved, then you might want to use a DATETIME or TIMESTAMP data type.

Comment: the reason i had it as VARCHAR is because i didnt know how to convert a unix timestamp to DD/MM/YY format.

Comment: Where are you trying to make the conversion, in the query or in the PHP script?

Comment: my problem is the date has to be input by tech-illiterate users so really i need a way to convert their DD/MM/YY input to a timestamp value and then back to DD/MM/YY when being displayed.

Comment: (another thing: the input for the date is through a form)
   <label for="eventdate">Date (DD/MM/YY):</label><br />
      <input name="eventdate" id="eventdate" type="text" maxlength="100" />

Comment: See my answer below, I think that covers everything we talked about here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on our little discussion above, it seems like the easiest thing to do is make your `eventdate` field an INT data type.  That way, when you take the user input as a string ("15/03/2011" for example), you can run that input through the PHP function `strtotime()` and get a UNIX timestamp from that.

```
<?php

$eventts = strtotime($_POST["eventdate"]);
$q = "UPDATE eventsDB SET eventdate = ".$eventts." WHERE keyfield = whatever";
$r = mysql_query($q);

?>
```

Note that `strtotime()` returns an INT (or boolean FALSE) so we're not setting you up for a SQL injection attack above.  To query the database, you could then do this:

```
<?php

$q = "SELECT *
      FROM eventsDB 
      WHERE eventdate > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() 
      ORDER BY eventdate ASC
      LIMIT 30";
$r = mysql_query($q);

?>
```

To answer your question in the comments to this answer:

```
if ( $_POST['eventdate'])
  $eventdate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['eventdate']);
```

Would be replaced with

```
if ( $_POST['eventdate'])
  $eventdate = strtotime($_POST['eventdate']);
```

---

Note that for a production system, I **really** wouldn't recommend putting the admin code in the same page as the display code, and you should use the `isset()` function to check whether a `$_POST` array variable has been set (lest you cause all sorts of warnings or notices in your web server logs).

---

To display the date, you'd use the PHP `date()` function, specifically:

```
$entry_display = date("d/m/Y", $eventdate);
```

Where `$eventdate` is the UNIX timestamp you retrieved from the database.

Comment: crontab im gonna put my code on the question, could you tell me where to add the:
.
$eventts = strtotime($_POST["eventdate"]);
$q = "UPDATE eventsDB SET eventdate = ".$eventts." WHERE keyfield = whatever";
$r = mysql_query($q);
.
that you suggested?

Comment: thanks for your quick response, really helpful! 
I know its not very secure right now, i hope to improve that later!

Comment: it works! the only problem i have now is displaying the INT value as DD/MM/YYYY on the page ($entry_display)

Answer (score 0):

The database is used or storing data.
PHP (or whatever you chose to use) is used for interacting with the user.

If you want to store a date, you should use a date datatype.

How you want to display the date, is up to your PHP code.

Probably you want to show the date in different formats depending on the visitor, or possible in ISO format so all of the world can read it: YYYY-MM-DD

So, your query is pretty much correct:

```
SELECT * 
FROM eventsDB 
WHERE  eventdate > NOW()
ORDER BY eventdate ASC 
LIMIT 30
```

Note that using 'SELECT *' is not recommended for production code. Only select the columns you need - it can mean better use of indices and less data transferred between your database and application server.

Answer (score 0):

You can store `eventdate` field as UNIX timestamp and then compare it easily in your queries.

```
SELECT ... WHERE `eventdate` > NOW() ...
```

and you can format it with php `date` function :

```
date('DD/MM/YY', $eventdate);
```

here is the manual : [PHP Date Function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)